# Multiple time periods comparison in Power BI / DAX

Tags: datetime, powerbi, comparison, dax, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a question regarding a multiple-year comparison report in Power BI and DAX. The first five columns in the below table show the example data, the sixth column shows the two requirements, and the last column shows whether a plan _ID in the first column meets the requirement. I hope to count the number of plan_IDs which meet both requirements for a specific season (e. g. Spring 2018).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFSSB.png)

As you can see from the last column, Spring 2018 has 3 "yes" while Spring 2019 has 6. Therefore, for Spring 2019, the "Count of Plans for This Year"  is 6 while the "Count of Plans for The Last Year" is 3, as shown in the table below. The table is what I want to have.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uoZJ.png)

My question is how to count the plans that meet the two requirements for a specific season/season_number such as Spring 2019/190.

I have been struggling in this situation for a long time. Any ideas or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How you define 2 Years ago, 3 years ago in the calculation? Is that current year (2020) - year(2018) + 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding (as commented) is correct, just add a **Custom Column** to your table as below in the **Power Query Editor**-

**Changed Type** in line 2 is basically the **Previous Step Name**. Adjust this accordigly.

```
= Table.AddColumn(
    #"Changed Type", 
    "counter or not", 
    each 
    let 
        current_year = Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()),
        year_difference = current_year - [year] + 1,
        current_date = DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()),
        date_to_check_with = Date.AddYears(current_date,-(year_difference)),
        meet_req = if [plan_date] <= date_to_check_with then "Yes" else "No"
    in meet_req
)
```

And here is the final output-

[image]

Now your the column with Yes/No value. To count Yes per year, come back to report and create this below **Measure**-

```
yearly_yes_count = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT(your_table_name[counted or not]),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT(your_table_name,your_table_name[year]),
        your_table_name[counted or not] = "Yes"
    )
)
```

Here is last year count-

```
last_year_yes_count = 

VAR current_row_year = MIN(your_table_name[year])

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    COUNT(your_table_name[counted or not]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[counted or not] = "Yes"
        && your_table_name[Year] = current_row_year - 1
    )
)
```

Now add **Year** and new measure **yearly_yes_count** to a table visual and the output will be as below-

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs! Could you please also help out how to get the "Count of Plans for This Year" and the "Count of Plans for The Last Year" by using DAX?

Comment: Your suggestion about adding the "counter or not" column works great! Could you please give me further suggestions about how to count plans for this year and last year? I'm looking forward to your help! Thanks again!

Comment: You can create dax for yearly count. Let me come back shortly.

Comment: Hi @R_R, I appreciate your kind inputs! My "Count of Plans for This Year"  column is the same as your "yearly-yes-count" column. My question is how to get the "Count of Plans for Last Year" . Thank you!

Comment: I used the below measure to count plans of last year, but it doesn't count.              
Count Plans of Last Year = CALCULATE(COUNT('Example Data'[Plan_ID]),FILTER('Example Data','Example Data'[Plan_Date]<='Example Data'[date_to_check_with] && 'Example Data'[counter or not]="Yes"))

Comment: The ideal result shows in my posted question on above. Thanks!

Comment: @NewStart2020, check my my updated answer. Added a new measure code.

Comment: I really appreciate your timely reply! I used your suggested measure to count plans of last year but got an error message "Too few arguments were passed to the ALLEXCEPT function. The minimum argument count for the function is 2."

Comment: last_year_yes_count = 

VAR current_row_year = MIN('Example Data'[Year])

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('Example Data'[counter or not]),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT('Example Data')///Here caused the error message,
        'Example Data'[counter or not] = "Yes" &&
        'Example Data'[counter or not] = current_row_year - 1
    )
)

Comment: sorry sorry sorry, updated the answer. please check.

Comment: Excellent! Your solution works great! I really appreciate your kind help. You're a Power BI expert!

Comment: Nice to hear it worked and helped. You can also put an up vote :)

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not able to vote at this time since my reputations are not good enough. Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputations are recorded but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 2):

One of the best ways is to create comparative table (with an inactive relationship with the fact table), the user will have the possibility to choose any two time perdiods and the single visual will show the comparison :

Here are two good videos explaining this subject fully:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TF0lPIYjJfs

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=knXFVf2ipro